# ObservableCollection binding to a view control

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, data-binding

How can I bind ObservableCollection to a custom view?

I have added custom view to a page:

MainPage.xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
   <vw:ResultsListView /> 
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Inside MainViewModel.cs there is this corresponding property:

```
private ObservableCollection<FertInspectionResult> _ResultsItems;
public ObservableCollection<FertInspectionResult> ResultsItems 
{ 
   get => _ResultsItems; 
   set => SetProperty(ref _ResultsItems, value); 
}
```

ResultListView is a simple collection view:

```
<ContentView.Content>

    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ResultsItems}">
        
        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
                <Label Text="{Binding SEQ}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
    
    </CollectionView>
  
</ContentView.Content>
```

I know this is not correct, but I am unable to find a way to create BindableProperty it such way that CollectionView would be filled.

Comment: Do you have a misspelling in your code? The property name is "ResultsItems" with a plural 's' at "Result" ... but your Binding contains only "ResultItems" without the plural 's'

Comment: Where is your ObservableCollection instantiated?

Comment: @JeroenvanLangen Somewhere else, that part is ok. Classic binding is working

Comment: I understand that you could not get bindableproperty to work, but its best if you show in question an attempt at declaring (and using) a bindableproperty in your custom component’s code behind. Give that property some name DIFFERENT THAN ItemsSource (for now). Then someone can help you fix it. Also, can you find some tutorial or example that uses bindableproperty in a custom component? If so, add link to one you attempt to follow. AFAIK, observable collection should work same as any other type.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Thanks for helpful answer... Do you think I didn´t try to find a tutorial? Maybe instead of this SO toxic sh!t you could just give me a real answer. If you don´t know why are you even here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a typo `ResultsItems` in xaml vs `ResultItems` in view model.
Also if `<vw:ResultsListView />` contain your collection, you should use namespace for getting collection.

Answer (score 0):

You can create your bindable property for your custom control in your [Xamarin.Forms Bindable Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties),just like that:

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty ResultsItemsSourceProperty =BindableProperty.Create("ResultsItemsSource", typeof(ObservableCollection<MyItem>), typeof(MyContentView), null);


    public ObservableCollection<MyItem> ResultsItemsSource
    {
        get => (ObservableCollection<MyItem>)GetValue(MyContentView.ResultsItemsSourceProperty);
        set => SetValue(MyContentView.ResultsItemsSourceProperty, value);
    }
```

Then in your MainPage.xaml, you could use your property created:

```
< vm:ResultListView ResultsItemsSource="{Binding ResultsItems}"  />
```

In your ResultListView, just setting the BindingContext of your CollectionView to your ContentView itself:

```
<ContentView
    ...
    x:Name="this">
<CollectionView  BindingContext="{x:Reference this}"     ItemsSource="{Binding ResultsItemsSource}">
```

And now you can bind ResultsItems which is generated in ViewModel to your ResultListView.

For more info, you could also refer to  [ContentView Demo](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/tree/main/UserInterface/ContentViewDemos).